# Expo - React Native: How to read User data from Google Fit API

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, google-fit, google-fit-api

thanks in advance for any assistance that can be provided. My goal is to use OAuth2 to get users’ step data from the Google Fit API. I am able to authenticate using Expo's expo-app-auth package, and receive an accessToken, but, when I try to read from the Fit API, I get an error that the authentication credential is missing.

Relevant Code:

```
let config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read'],
  /* This is the CLIENT_ID generated from a Firebase project */
  clientId: 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
};

let authState = await AppAuth.authAsync(config); // this returns an idToken, accessToken, list of scopes configured, including the fitness.activity.read

const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate';
const today = new Date().getTime();
const past = today - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100);
const body = {
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": today,
  "endTimeMillis": past
}

const header = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `BEARER ${authState.accessToken}`
}

const req = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: header,
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
});

const resp = await req.json();
/*
Object {
  "error": Object {
    "code": 401,
    "errors": Array [
      Object {
        "domain": "global",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header",
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "reason": "required",
      },
    ],
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
  },
}
*/
```

I am able to produce this issue using a built apk on a real device. For the standalone build, I am using an OAuth2 clientId from Google Console as clientId in the config, and the Fitness API is enabled.

Does anyone know what I might be doing incorrectly?